# How can I access nodes from jumpbox using SSH on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have used Azure arm template ( 
[azure-quickstart-templates/mongodb-high-availability](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/mongodb-high-availability) ) to create Mongodb VMs like master-slave.
I got the details of ssh for Jumpbox only but I'm not getting how to connect mongodb Vm nodes from jumpbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following steps:

1.SSH to your Jumpbox VM.

2.Get your mongodb VM node private IP on Azure Portal.
[image]

3.SSH to your node VMs, the user and password is same with Jumpbox VM.

Comment: thank you @walter for an answer.  I 'll let know about the same

Comment: can you explain in more detailed?

Comment: Hi, could you get your db private ip? I notice that you ask a new question. Now, you use this template or MongoDB with replication(Bitnami) .

Comment: @TailorDevendra Sorry for my mistake. I refer Bitnami article. You need use `sudo service bitnami restart` to restart your Mongodb.